# Converting rows to columns with no numeric common field

Tags: sql-server

Could anyone please assist me in converting rows to columns for the following data:

```
Booking FirstName   LastName     EmailAddress
AAAAA   Jamie       James        Jamie.James@mail.com
AAAAA   Birdy       James        Birdy.James@mail.com
AAAAA   Kirby       James        Kirby.James@mail.com
BBBBB   Christine   Elliott      Christine.elliott@mail.com
```

So after conversion it should look like this:

```
Booking FirstName   LastName     EmailAddress
AAAAAA  Jamie       James        Jamie.James@mail.com   Birdy       James        Birdy.James@mail.com  Kirby        James        Kirby.James@mail.com
BBBBB   Christine   Elliott      Christine.elliott@mail.com
```

The Pivot or Case won't work here as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Irfan.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Are those extra columns or values concatenated in the same column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is just a standard.

Comment: Sorry its SQL Server!

Comment: Why do you want the extra columns?  This is generally not how SQL should be used and transformation such as this should be handled by the application that you are using to present the data, using the first dataset in your question.